# Jquery - Display element on <select> change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched and searched but my jquery/js skills are so poor I can't get it to work.

What I desire is for each option in the selection a different  is displayed for further information.

```
<label class="checklabel">Is it possible to recieve mail?</label>
<select class="mailoption">
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<div class="yesmail">Yes can recieve mail.</div>
<div class="nomail">No can't recieve mail.</div>
```

When the value is 1 it should display 'yesmail' and option 2 should display 'nomail'. I've tried several lines of coding gathered from stackoverflow but I all had to adjust it which I can't do to this degree.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you made any attempt at doing this? If so could you update the source code with your attempt. Update with anything you have tried and i'm sure people will help you from there.

Comment: Instead of classes, use `id`s like `mail1` and `mail2`, then select a correct `div` by concatenating `"mail"` and the value of `select` in `.getElementById()`'s argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have had problems with selecting the DOM elements. As @Teemu points out you might want to use `id`s instead. You can  use `$(".foobar")` to select the elements with the `class` foobar and `$("#foobar")` to select the element with `id` foobar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mailoption").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 1) {
            $(".yesmail").removeClass('hidden');
            $(".nomail").addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(".yesmail").addClass('hidden');
            $(".nomail").removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checklabel">Is it possible to recieve mail?</label>
<select class="mailoption">
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<div class="yesmail">Yes can recieve mail.</div>
<div class="nomail hidden">No can't recieve mail.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I guess what I did wrong was  == "1").